# ActionMailer not sending emails properly if the :to field has a comma

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, actionmailer

One of my mailers looks like this:

```
mail(:from => "Support Team <support@email.com>",
     :to => "#{@user.alias} <#{@user.email}>",
     :subject => 'Verification Email')
```

However, if the alias of the user is "Foobar, Bar", then the email actually gets sent to: `Foobar, Bar <foobar@gmail.com>`. i.e. to foobar and to composer.

I think the problem is with the comma in "Foobar, Bar". Does this need to be escaped or something?

Should my mailer look like this instead:

```
mail(:from => "Support Team <support@email.com>",
     :to => @user.email,
     :subject => 'Verification Email')
```

Comment: thanx very much for this question. I was having a tough time with similar problem in from.

Thanx again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Certainly spaces (and possibly commas) in the name part of an email header must be included within quotes.

Quoting a name is sometimes optional, but never forbidden, so for simplicity, try:

```
mail(:from => "\"Support Team\" <support@email.com>",
     :to => "\"#{@user.alias}\" <#{@user.email}>",
     :subject => 'Verification Email')
```

**EDIT** For completeness, I have added escaped quotes to `from`, because they should also be necessary.

Comment: Any benefits or disadvantages if it was just `:from => support@email.com` and `:to => @user.email`. Does this affect deliver-ability in any way?

Comment: Adding names does not affect delivery at all (unless it's done in an invalid way and trashes the message). It's personal choice. With the "To" address, it's only relevant to use a name if you want to help recipients identify each other (or to help you when reviewing sent items). It can be annoying to receive a message with your own name completed incorrectly, so it might be better all-round to use the email address in "To". Including a name in "From" helps the recipient know who you are. It generally looks better than just an email address, so if you can include your name in "From", I'd do it.

Comment: Thanx buddy. gr8 solution.